# Flink web UI authentication

Tags: security, authentication, apache-flink

Does flink support authentication of flink web UI like any username/password way of authentication.

If yes, then does this require any third party applications such as key cloak etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flink does not directly support authenticating access to the web UI, but you can always put something like nginx in front of it.

Comment: Is there any flink documentation page that say so? It would be great if you could provide me some link. Thank you

Comment: http://apache-flink-mailing-list-archive.1008284.n3.nabble.com/flink-web-ui-authentication-td21526.html
find the dev mailing discussion here.