# Flink web UI : How to remove "cancel" button from flink web UI

Tags: apache-flink

I am deploying flink application on Production but there is "cancel" button on flink web UI which can create issue as I will be able to cancel the job without logging in production server through proper channel.

Is there any way to remove/disable that "cancel" button.

Comment: Hi, did u solve this issue or any alternative method??

Comment: No i didnt. Only was is to not provide UI at all in production

Answer (score 1):

Set [`web.cancel.enable`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/config/#web-cancel-enable) to `false`.

From the docs:

> Enables canceling jobs through the Flink UI (true by default). Please note that even when this is disabled, session clusters still cancel jobs through REST requests (HTTP calls). This flag only guards the feature to cancel jobs in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Flink UI supports any such functionality. Check these web configuration - [Flink Web Frontend Configurations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#web-frontend), you **won't find any config** which lets us disable the cancel button.

You can try exploring a workaround web UI authentication as per this SO answer - [Flink web UI authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254307/flink-web-ui-authentication)